# How to share @MockBeans and mock methods among my tests without inheritance?

Tags: spring, inheritance, junit, mocking, integration-testing

I have a base test scenario that will be used by other integration tests. This scenario includes some mock beans (`@MockBean`) for external integrations.

Today, I have something like this in the integration test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class OrderIT {
```

And the fields and annotations to prepare my integration test:

```
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper mapper;

@MockBean
private SomeGateway someGateway;

@MockBean
private SomeRabbitMqService someRabbitMqService ;

@MockBean
private AnotherRabbitMqService anotherRabbitMqService;

@MockBean
private SomeIntegrationService someIntegrationService ;

@MockBean
private Clock clock;

@Before
public void setup() {
    //some methods mocking each service above, preparing mockMvc, etc
}
```

This scenario is necessary for use the `MockMvc` and create the main feature in the system, my `Order`. This `Order` is created by calling a POST method in a Rest API, saving the `order` in a memory database.

Even this working well, I need to **duplicate** this block of code containing these `@MockBean` and some `@Autowired` in another tests, because the `Order` is the **base scenario** to add Products to the order, set an Address to deliver, etc. Each scenario has a different integration test but all of them needs an `Order`.

So, how to share the "MockBeans" and the methods that mocks them among my Integration Tests? I had really **bad experiences using inheritance** among the tests and I really would like to try a different approach.

Comment: "So, how to share the "MockBeans" and the methods that mock them among my Integration Tests? " You don't have thousand solutions to share some fields: inheritance or composition. The first one is less verbose of course.

Comment: What's the purpose of this test? Seems every dependent component is being mocked and the purpose of an integration test is precisely test the interaction between dependent services.

Comment: @ootero Call an API Rest and save/update/delete/get the `Order` (and related entities), saving in a database memory (H2 and Embedded MongoDB). There are a lot of other services (the order and related services) being tested in this process.  I'm only mocking the external dependencies (events from/to RabbitMQ and WebService, basically), but there are some annotation setup (mapper, mockMvc, wac) that need to be repeated only to do a Rest Call on Spring and that bothers me too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I end up using the [Spring profiles](https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles).

I created a configuration class annotated with `@Profile("test")` and created the mocked beans there. Like:

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class MyMockConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SomeService someService() {
        SomeService someService = mock(SomeService .class);
        // mocked methods and results
        return someService ;
    }
```

And in the Test class:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyControllerIT {
```

If some integration test needs to override the current mock implementation on the profile, the test just needs to declare `@MockBean` on the class and proceed on the mock as usual.

I'm not decide yet if `test` is a good name, because for me makes more sense mock the configuration by "context". So, instead of use the generic name `test` on the profile name, I could use `createOrder` and have different configuration profiles, each one with a different name and different mocks: `createOrder`, `createOrderWithoutProducts`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `@ContextConfiguration` was created for this purpose:  https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles